# Radial stripes in sketch

Tags: vector, shapes, sketch-app

What is the best way to create these radial stripes (background) in sketch?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

1. Draw a triangle.

[image: Triangle in Sketch]

2. Select "Layer > Paths > Rotate Copies". Choose however many copies you want in the circle -- 24, for example.
3. Drag the center point to the tip of the original triangle.

(And if you want these triangles confined to a rounded rectangle, just mask it.)

[image: Dragging the center point]

Comment: works perfectly!